# MVC3- ASP.NET-Logged In Person-Different Methods

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to find out the logged in person

What is the Difference between the following.

`string loggedInName = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name.ToString();`

```
   string loggedInName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString();
```

I am asking this question because I cannot use the Second one in Controller. It gives the following Error

```
System.Web.HttpContextBase' does not contain a definition for 'Current' and no extension method 'Current' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.HttpContextBase' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **HttpContext.Current** is a static method
>   that return the current http context,
>   while **Context** is an instance method
>   defined in the page class that returns
>   the current http context (it really
>   just calls the above function).

Answer (score 2):

They are identical only if you're not working with threads; System.Web.HttpContext.Current contains the value which is tied to the thread. That is, in any additional thread, you cannot access HttpContext.Current.